# How to extract result from lme() function from multiple groups and then combine in R?

Tags: r, extract, resultset

First, the following data are split randomly into two groups according to the `sl` variable and then run the model for both groups  using the for loop shown below the data set

```
mydata
              y  x sl
    1  5.297967  1  1
    2  3.322833  2  1
    3  4.969813  3  1
    4  4.276666  4  1
    5  5.972807  1  2
    6  6.619440  2  2
    7  8.045588  3  2
    8  7.377759  4  2
    9  6.907755  5  2
    10 8.672486  6  2
    11 8.283999  7  2
    12 8.455318  8  2
    13 7.414573  9  2
    14 8.634087 10  2
    15 7.356355  1  3
    16 6.606247  2  3
    17 6.396930  9  3
    18 6.579251 10  3
    19 5.521110  1  4
    20 2.224221  2  4
    21 6.742881  3  4
    22 6.709304  4  4
    23 6.875232  5  4
    24 8.476371  6  4
    25 7.360104  7  4
```

Runnign model using lme() function for both group and then store the `beta`  coefficients as matrix and `theta`[ random intercept term ] as vector

```
sl.no=unique(mydata$sl)
m=length(unique(mydata$sl))
ngrp=2
set.seed(125)
idx=sample(1:ngrp, size=m, replace = T)

beta=matrix(NA, nrow = ngrp, ncol=3, byrow=T) #null matrix to store coefficients from both groups 
theta=rep(0,m) #null vector to store intercepts from both groups
library(nlme)
for ( g in 1:ngrp){
  rg=sl.no[idx==g]
  mydata_rG=mydata[mydata$sl %in% rg,] #Data set belongs to group-g


  lme_mod=lme(y~x+I(x^2),random = ~ 1|sl,
                  data = mydata_rG, method = "ML") #mixed effect model for each group


  beta[g,]=c(unlist(lme_mod$coefficients[1])[[1]],
             unlist(lme_mod$coefficients[1])[[2]],
             unlist(lme_mod$coefficients[1])[[3]])
  theta=c(unname(lme_mod$coefficients$random$sl))


}
```

I am expecting a `theta` vector of length m. Unfortunately, `theta` comes as the size of one.
Any help is appreciated.

results of `beta` and `theta`

```
beta
         [,1]       [,2]        [,3]
[1,] 4.895805  0.7954474 -0.05602771
[2,] 6.423533 -1.7441753  0.32049662

theta
[1] 4.264366e-21 #it should be length of m.
```

Comment: `theta[g]=...`? By the way, doesn't *sl* have 4 groups, not 2?

Comment: there are two groups, according to the split, group 1 has three `sl`, and group 2 has one. So for group one, I will have three `theta`s for group-1and one` theta` for the group-2

Comment: please see `idx`. it takes value either `1 ` (for group-1) or `2` (for group-2). The `rg` is created to identify which of the `sl` should go for group-g`(1 or 2)`

Comment: Got it. Very subtle. Usually for groups, it is expected to be reflected in data. So does my earlier question to index `theta` with `g` not resolve your issue?

Comment: No, `theta[g]` is not working :(

Comment: Here is the warning  message

`In theta[g] <- c(unname(lme_mod$coefficients$random$sl)) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: Issue may be right-hand side as it may return `NULL` or more than one item. Wrap with `tryCatch` and check NAs in result *theta* vector: `theta[g] <- tryCatch(c(unname(lme_mod$coefficients$random$sl)), warning = function(w) NA, error = function(e) NA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only about how you store `theta` values

```
sl.no=unique(mydata$sl)
m=length(unique(mydata$sl))
ngrp=2
set.seed(125)
idx=sample(1:ngrp, size=m, replace = T)

beta=matrix(NA, nrow = ngrp, ncol=3, byrow=T) 
theta=numeric() #Change here
library(nlme)
for ( g in 1:ngrp){
   rg=sl.no[idx==g]
   mydata_rG=mydata[mydata$sl %in% rg,] 

  lme_mod=lme(y~x+I(x^2),random = ~ 1|sl,
          data = mydata_rG, method = "ML") 


  beta[g,]=c(unlist(lme_mod$coefficients[1])[[1]],
             unlist(lme_mod$coefficients[1])[[2]],
             unlist(lme_mod$coefficients[1])[[3]])
   theta=c(theta, unname(lme_mod$coefficients$random$sl)) #Change here

}
```